# Android circle bitmap center label not properly center

Tags: android, bitmap

I have a square bitmap (200*200). This bitmap has a background color (YELLOW) and a letter in its center (imagine an A).
From that bitmap I want to create a rounded bitmap with a black border. This border would be 4 pixels, so the final image that I pretend is an bitmap of 220*220 with a circle with a radius of 100 at its center and a border of 4. If I look at this bitmap I would see a rounded circle with a black border at its center and with some transparent pixels (16) on the sides.

I'm doing this:

```
float scaleWidth = ((float) destWidth) / width;
float scaleHeight = ((float) destHeight) / height;

float scale = Math.max(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postScale(scale, scale);

Bitmap roundBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(destWidth + 20, destHeight + 20, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888) // This creates a square bitmap of 220*220

BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, TileMode.CLAMP, TileMode.CLAMP); // The original size of bitmap is 200*200
shader.setLocalMatrix(matrix);

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setShader(shader);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(roundBitmap);
canvas.drawCircle((destWidth + 20) / 2, (destHeight + 20) / 2, destWidth / 2, paint)
```

THe image is created like this:

[image]

How can I center the letter A?

In the left I got the original image (bitmap) and on the left (roundBitmap) I got want I want except the label centered:

[image]

Comment: did anybody spotted the two 'if if...' in the question?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: would have been a good exercise for some.but anyways is your letter centered in your square bitmap?

Comment: In the original image it is

Comment: can you post how your original image is and what you want it to look like

Comment: Just edited the question

Comment: try changing your scale to `float scaleWidth = (((float) destWidth)+20) / width;
float scaleHeight = (((float) destHeight)+20) / height;`

Comment: Hello. Sorry for the late response. That also increases the label. In this case the A increases a bit but since my image is in fact very small (50*50) its neglectable. Thanks. Please provide as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your image size is same all time then you should modify your code as below

```
scaleWidth = (((float) destWidth)+20) / width; float scaleHeight = (((float) destHeight)+20) / height;
```

Answer (score 1):

Chris Banes wrote a post about this exact issue.
[Measuring Text](https://chris.banes.me/2014/03/27/measuring-text/).